# Build model in unit test

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

Just wanted some guidance how would I go about unit testing the following action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = _resolver.GetService<ISignUpViewModel>();
    model.Location =  _resolver.GetService<ILocations>().getLocations(string area);
    return PartialView("Login", model);
}


private IDependencyResolver _resolverMock;

[TestMethod]
public void SignUpTest()
{
    var _resolverMock = new Mock<IDependencyResolver>();
    var ctrl = new HomeController(_resolverMock.Object);
    var signUpMock = new Mock<ISignUpViewModel>();
    var LocationsMock = new Mock<ILocations>();

    _resolverMock.Setup(m => m.GetService(It.IsAny<Type>())).Returns(
             signUpMock.Object);

   _resolverMock.Setup(m => m.GetService(It.IsAny<Type>())).Returns(
             LocationsMock.Object);


    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(resolverMock.Object);

    ctrl.Index();
    ctrl.ViewData.Model = signUpMock;
}
```

How do you build up the model in the unit test?

Also how do I call the getLocations method from the resolver?

Unsure on how to do this?

Comment: The getLocations returns a IEnumerable<SelectListItem>

Comment: Your controller has a dependency on an ISignUpViewModelFactory which would have a create method public ISignUpViewModel Create(string area) {}. I would be passing this interface into the controller constructor and calling that in your action method. As it stands you are using a servicelocator _resolver and you're right they are a PITA to test against.

Comment: Can you give me an example in code don't quite follow you.

Answer (score 0):

Your home controller is not dependent on an `IDependencyResolver` as per your code. It is in fact dependent on an `ISignUpViewModel`. So you can either pass one of those into the constructor or an `ISignUpViewModelFactory`. So I would refactor the model resolution out into a factory class:

```
public class HomeController {

    private readonly ISignUpViewModelFactory _modelFactory;

    public HomeController(ISignUpViewModelFactory modelFactory){
          _modelFactory = modelFactory;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return PartialView("Login", _modelFactory.Create(area));
    }
}


public interface ISignUpViewModelFactory {
  ISignUpViewModel Create(string area);
}

public class ProductionSignUpViewModelFactory : ISignUpViewModelFactory
{
    public ISignUpViewModel Create(string area){
       // create and return your models here
       // if you still have to use a service locator in this factory then
       // refactor some more until you get these dependencies out in the open.
    }
}

public class MockSignUpViewModelFactory : ISignUpViewModelFactory
{
    public ISignUpViewModel Create(string area){
       return new SignUpViewModel();
    }
}
```

In production you have your `IOC` inject an instance of  `ProductionSignUpViewModelFactory`. In test, you pass in a `MockSignUpViewModelFactory`.

The difference is that using this method you are only testing the action (i.e. the unit) whereas using your current method you are testing the action AND your servicelocator `_resolver` plus you've obscured the actual dependency i.e. `ISignUpViewModel` not `IDependencyResolver`.

As per the comments in `ProductionSignUpViewModelFactory`, if you have to inject an `IDependencyResolver` into that factory to make it work then you're probably still doing it wrong. You then need to look at what `ProductionSignUpViewModelFactory` needs to create an instance of `ISignUpViewModel` and inject that not an `IDependencyResolver`.

Eventually you'll get to the top of your dependency chain and you'll find unit testing becomes very, very easy. It's even easier if you build the tests first i.e. TDD. :)

Comment: So if I have another action with the similar setup i.e. create an new user I would have to have another constructor that takes INewUser and another MockNewUserFactory. The aim is to get the HomeController to be very thin?

Comment: Yep that's very likely. You might find your single controller is actually 3 or 4 controllers. I know it sounds like more work (it's actually not) but in the long run so much easier. You will have extra classes using this method but IMHO it's the only way to go, specially for test and if your using visual studio to generate the scaffs anyway, then it's almost no extra work at all. The aim is not so much to get it "thin" but just to self describe and be testable. Those hidden deps obscure the meaning of the class. I have to look inside it to see what it needs but the signature should be enough.

Comment: I will give this a go and let you know how I get on. Thanks